# WPF Flicker Popup Window Near MouseCursor

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I try to show a popup window in WPF next to the mouse cursor. The window position will be updated during the mouse move event. The main window is like this:

```
    <Grid x:Name="_layoutGrid" Background="Transparent">
    <DockPanel Background="Green"/>
    <Popup Name="_cursorInfo" 
           IsHitTestVisible="False"
           AllowsTransparency="True" 
           Placement="Relative" 
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=_layoutGrid}">
        <Border CornerRadius="1" Padding="1" Background="Blue" Opacity="0.7" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <TextBlock Text="Here is a content" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

The event handler for the mouse move is like this:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _layoutGrid.MouseMove += LayoutGrid_MouseMove;
        _layoutGrid.MouseLeave += LayoutGrid_MouseLeave;
    }
    private void LayoutGrid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _cursorInfo.IsOpen = false;
    }

    private void LayoutGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.GetPosition(_layoutGrid);
        if (!_cursorInfo.IsOpen)
        {
            _cursorInfo.IsOpen = true;
        }
        _cursorInfo.HorizontalOffset = pos.X;
        _cursorInfo.VerticalOffset = pos.Y;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Pos: {pos}");
    }
```

The popup shows up but there is a lot of "flicker". It seems the mouse is shortly captured in the popup which causes the flicker. I also recognized that when I remove the background of the contained border the flicker is gone. However I want to see a colored background for the border. I thought that setting the "IsHitTestVisible" is enough but it seems I am wrong. Any idea how I could avoid the flicker?

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is probably caused by the code in your `LayoutGrid_MouseLeave` which closes the `Popup`. You need to add some additional check in this event handler to verify the actual position of the mouse pointer relative to the `Grid`, e.g.:

```
private void LayoutGrid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(_layoutGrid);
    if (p.X >= 0 && p.Y >= 0 && p.X <= _layoutGrid.ActualWidth && p.Y <= _layoutGrid.ActualHeight)
        return;

    _cursorInfo.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: The flicker is gone, but when you move the mouse fast - so that the pointer is over the popup - the popup won't move anymore. It seems that even if IsHitTestVisible is false, the popup "steals" the mouse events.

Comment: @FranzGsell: When `IsHitTestVisible` is `false`, no mouse events are being raised. Remove the `IsHitTestVisible="False"` from the `Border`to make the `Popup` follow the mouse pointer.